# Flutter : Failed to get binder for service "vendor.vpsservice"

Tags: flutter, performance, terminal, vendor, android-binder

**Flutter dummy app creates an issue.**

I created a new app and run it on an android real device. It's show me an issue continuously on terminal like

```
Performing hot restart...                                               
Restarted application in 1,415ms.
E/VpsExtension( 3820): Failed to get binder for service "vendor.vpsservice"
E/VpsExtension( 3820): Failed to get binder for service "vendor.vpsservice"
E/VpsExtension( 3820): Failed to get binder for service "vendor.vpsservice"
E/VpsExtension( 3820): Failed to get binder for service "vendor.vpsservice"
E/VpsExtension( 3820): Failed to get binder for service "vendor.vpsservice"
E/VpsExtension( 3820): Failed to get binder for service "vendor.vpsservice"
E/VpsExtension( 3820): Failed to get binder for service "vendor.vpsservice"
E/VpsExtension( 3820): Failed to get binder for service "vendor.vpsservice"
E/VpsExtension( 3820): Failed to get binder for service "vendor.vpsservice"
E/VpsExtension( 3820): Failed to get binder for service "vendor.vpsservice"
E/VpsExtension( 3820): Failed to get binder for service "vendor.vpsservice"
E/VpsExtension( 3820): Failed to get binder for service "vendor.vpsservice"
```

Why is it showing ? How can I stop this message?

Comment: Hei Abir did you solve this problem I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: Not yet. Please, like on my question, if you face the same problem, that's why some one will interested to solve this.